# Sub navigation doesn't work properly when hovered when page is marked active

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a nav-bar and sub-nav bar like this:

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class=<?php if ($currentPage=='about') 
echo ' "active" '; ?> "dropdown"><a href="http://link/about.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ABOUT</a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="abt-firstcell"><a href="http://link/about.php">OUR STORY</a></li>
                <li class="abt-secondcell"><a href="http://link/our_team.php">OUR TEAM</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li <?php if ($currentPage=='advertising') 
echo ' class="active" '; ?> class="dropdown"><a href="http://link/advertising-how.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ADVERTISING</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="adv-firstcell"><a href="http://link/advertising-how.php">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>

                <li class="adv-secondcell"><a href="#">OUR PARTNERS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</div>
```

CSS of it:

```
.abt-secondcell{
text-align:left;
}
.abt-firstcell{
width:500px;
padding-left:30px;
text-align:right;
border-right:2px solid black;
}
.adv-secondcell{
text-align:left;
}
.adv-firstcell{
width:500px;
padding-right:0;
padding-left:450px;
text-align:right;
border-right:2px solid black;
}

.nav { margin-bottom: 0; }
.nav > li.dropdown:hover { position: static; }
.nav > li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu, .nav > li.active:hover                .dropdown-menu {
display:table; 
width: 100%; 
text-align: center; 
left:0; 
right:0; 
background:#E1E0DE;

}
.dropdown-menu>li{
display: table-cell;

}
```

I followed [this example](http://www.bootply.com/8EgGsi4F7w) to create the subnav bar on bootstrap 3 to work on hover. But now the problem is, when a page is ACTIVE, the subnav bar doesn't work as it is supposed to. I am quite sure this is a problem with the CSS but can't really figure out what's happening. On every page, I declare `$currentPage` to be something so that the header knows what page it is in.

The problem is, when I am in the About page, it's active and when I hover on the About tab, doesn't work properly like when it works when I hover on Advertising. Basically the ACTIVE tag messes it up. Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 `class` attribute on the same element, change it to:

```
<li class="dropdown<?php if ($currentPage=='advertising') echo ' active'; ?>">
```

(And do the same for the other instances)